# Using awk to get the numbers in column / 1024. Then work out 40 % of each and return that and column 1

Tags: bash, csv, awk, grep

I am trying to write an awk statement that will take a column (column 2) of  a CSV containing numbers with two decimal places. Divide each number by 1024 to convert Mb to Gb, then get the value that is 40% of that. So the number would look like this

```
Column_1,5677.38
```

Take that number divide it by 1024. Then divide it by 100 and multiply by 40.
Something like:

```
awk -F "," '{print $1, $2/(1024) multiply by 100 times 40}'
```

My guess is

```
awk -F "," '{print $1, $2/(1024)/(100) * 40}'
```

Comment: Seems OK, which is the problem/question?

Comment: You can also just multiply by `.40` instead of dividing by 100 and multiplying by 40.

Comment: There's no need to put `1024` and `100` in parentheses.

Comment: In fact, he could just multiply by 0,000390625, but the point is that his current answer seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't set `OFS` you'll lose the delimiter (default is space)

I would write it this way

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1, $2*0.4/1024}' file
```

for formatting number of decimal digits you may want to use `printf` instead.